# Is there a yasnippet producing a prepopulated doxygen comment?

Tags: yasnippet, c++

For the following C++ function:

```
bool importantStuff(double a, double b);
```

It should output the following snippet, perhaps without the tags:

```
/**
 * <Insert description of importantStuff>
 *
 * @param a <Insert description of a>
 * @param b <Insert description of b>
 * @return <Insert description of the return value>
 */
```

I've looked around the net, but the closest I've gotten to an answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324752/emacs-c-c-doxygen-alternative-to-doxymacs-with-yasnippet) old SO question where the answer depends on the no longer maintained doxymacs mode.

Comment: I think `c-sharp-mode` has something that does this.

Comment: Do you want to do this for new functions or existing ones?

Comment: When asking the question I was thinking about the doxygen comment being generated from the signature of the function.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following which is a mashup of the standard doxymacs based one and abo-abo's semantic based one mentioned as an answer already - this only requires semantic and yasnippet. This pre-populates some more of the yasnippet placeholders with relevant info as well compared to abo-abo 's version too.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: dox
# key: dox
# type: command
# --
(unless (and (fboundp 'semantic-current-tag)
             semantic-mode)
  (error "Semantic required to use dox snippet"))
(let ((tag (senator-next-tag)))
  (while (or (null tag)
             (not (semantic-tag-of-class-p tag 'function)))
    (setq tag (senator-next-tag)))
  (let* ((name (semantic-tag-name tag))
         (attrs (semantic-tag-attributes tag))
         (args (plist-get attrs :arguments))
         (return-name (plist-get attrs :type))
         (idx 1))
    (if (listp return-name)
      (setq return-name (car return-name)))
    (yas/expand-snippet
     (format
      "/**
* @brief ${1:%s}
*
%s
%s*/
"
      name
      (mapconcat
       (lambda (x)
         (format "* @param %s ${%d:Description of %s}"
                 (car x) (incf idx) (car x)))
       args
       "\n")
      (if (and return-name (not (string-equal "void" return-name)))
          (format " * @return ${%d:%s}\n" (incf idx) return-name)
        "")))))
```

Comment: This solution absolutely works, but having to wait for semantic mode to chug through all the required code is slightly cumbersome. I've also had emacs getting stuck in endless loops if I write dox<tab> before a variable instead. But one can't have everything in this world :D

Comment: this should be voted higher than the above, as it is richer than moo-doxygen

Comment: what command do i use to execute this function and generate documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Just added this feature to [function-args](https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args).

Here's the code, if you're interested. It's using CEDET:

```
(defun moo-doxygen ()
  "Generate a doxygen yasnippet and expand it with `aya-expand'.
The point should be on the top-level function name."
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (let ((tag (semantic-current-tag)))
    (unless (semantic-tag-of-class-p tag 'function)
      (error "Expected function, got %S" tag))
    (let* ((name (semantic-tag-name tag))
           (attrs (semantic-tag-attributes tag))
           (args (plist-get attrs :arguments))
           (ord 1))
      (setq aya-current
            (format
             "/**
* $1
*
%s
* @return $%d
*/
"
             (mapconcat
              (lambda (x)
                (format "* @param %s $%d"
                        (car x) (incf ord)))
              args
              "\n")
             (incf ord)))
      (aya-expand))))
```

You also need [auto-yasnippet](https://github.com/abo-abo/auto-yasnippet). Both packages are available
in MELPA.