# Can't get automated c++ docstrings to work

Tags: yasnippet

I stumbled [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8006/is-there-a-yasnippet-producing-a-prepopulated-doxygen-comment/8090#8090?newreg=f67ba38b109a4539a4f3b2303cf6bd41) and at first, it seems glorious, but I simply cannot get it to work. So when I try it on any program e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

bool helloWorld(int a,int b){
    dox<tab>
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
    return true
}

int main(){
std::cout << helloWorld(123, 321) std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

even though I have semantic-, doxy- and yas-mode enabled, it returns:

```
function: main (start)
[yas] Error running #[128 \302\300\303\301""\207 [eval ((progn (unless 
    (and (fboundp (quote semantic-current-tag)) semantic-mode) 
    (error Semantic required to use dox snippet)) (let ((tag 
    (senator-next-tag))) (while (or (null tag) (not (semantic-tag-of-class-p 
    tag (quote function)))) (setq tag (senator-next-tag))) (let* ((name 
    (semantic-tag-name tag)) (attrs (semantic-tag-attributes tag)) 
    (args (plist-get attrs :arguments)) (return-name (plist-get attrs :type)) 
    (idx 1)) (if (listp return-name) (setq return-name (car return-name))) 
    (yas/expand-snippet (format /**
* @brief ${1:%s}
*
%s
%s*/
name (mapconcat (lambda (x) (format * @param %s ${%d:Description of %s} (car x) 
    (incf idx) (car x))) args 
) (if (and return-name (not (string-equal void return-name))) 
    (format  * @return ${%d:%s}
(incf idx) return-name) ))))))) apply append] 6 

(fn &rest ARGS2)]: Symbol’s function definition is void: incf
```

I'm currently running ubuntu 16.04 and emacs25

Comment: Please format your error message.

Comment: Hope this is the format you're looking for ^_^

Comment: Nope, currently unreadable.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Second line stretches way, way, way to the right.  Please try to format it so that it can be read like code (ie, vertically).

Comment: `Semantic required to use dox snippet` - have you tried `M-x semantic-mode`?

Comment: Ahh, that way. Didn't really think about it. Just figured that part out regarding semantic, I should've seen that, though it still isn't working. Changing the question to the appropriate error

Comment: @Dan to be fair, I expect that's what the error message itself looks like. I think the code is just the same as what's in the linked thread anyway (though wrapped in bytecode function)

Comment: @npostavs: that's correct.  My point is that it's hard to read as is, and OP is more likely to get people to help if they don't have to work super hard to read the error message.  (Glad you did, though.)

Comment: Newbie OP here, did what you recommended, thanks for pointing the format out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Symbol’s function definition is void: incf
> ```

You can replace the `incf` calls in the snippet with `cl-incf`, or `M-x load-library RET cl RET`.

```
incf is an alias for ‘cl-incf’ in ‘cl.el’.
```

By the way, I think the `dox` is supposed to be expanded from above the function, not inside it.

Comment: Figured it out just as you posted, thanks for the answer though. I like it better in there instead of having to load even more packages on startup, AND you are right about where to use it.
Thanks for a pleasant experience for my first post in here :)

Answer (score 0):

So investigated a little and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119802/symbols-function-definition-is-void-incf-common-lisp-function-in-emacs24) which is to include the Common Lisp functions with

```
(require 'cl)
```

in the .emacs file, or init.el if you are into that one insead.